# How to delete a junction link where the target doesn't exist?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ntfs, junction

I have a directory junction whose target doesn't exist anymore and I want to delete said junction. Sounds easy enough but I get errors when I try:

```
> rd Documents
Access is denied.

> fsutil reparsepoint delete %USERPROFILE%\Documents
Error: The system cannot find the file specified.
A local NTFS volume is required for this operation.
```

How do I delete this junction?

Comment: Have you tried with Administrator privileges?

Comment: Why is the current working directory not showing in the prompt? This is likely highly relevant.

Comment: Not necessarily. I have my prompt set to `prompt=$G$S` which displays as `> `

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes.

Comment: @kreemoweet The current directory is shown in the prompt, I just did not write it out here.

Comment: Try this: Move everything else to a temp directory, use "rd /s folder", then rename the temp folder to the original name.

Comment: @harrymc I don't know if I can, the parent directory of the junction is my `%USERPROFILE%` directory.